# Finding the equivalence class and quotient set of relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I have the relation: $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: xRy \Leftrightarrow |x - 3| = |y - 3| $

I need to find the equivalence class and quotient set of the relation.

I think the equivalence class is:

$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: Cl(x) = \left \{ x  \right \} $

but I don't know if it it is a valid answer.

And also I don't know how to represent the quotient set since it's infinite, but it would be the set of all the classes for every x in R.

Comment: Start with one example. What is the equivalence class of $0$?

Comment: The equivalence class of 0 is $ Cl(0) = \left \{ 0 \right \} $I think.

Comment: Solve $|0-3|=3=|y-3|$ for $y$. There are two solutions.

Comment: Words might help: two points are equivalent if they are the same distance from $3$. That should tell you how large each equivalence class is, and what the set of classes looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct.

$|x-3|=|y-3|\Leftrightarrow x-3=y-3 \, OR \, x-3=3-y \Leftrightarrow x=y \, OR \, x+y=6.$ 
E.g., the equivalence class of $4$ is $\{2,4\}$. 
Equivalence classes can be represented by numbers greater than or equal to $3$.

Comment: I think I just got this, but how would you write the quotient set then?

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler way than the one in Chris Custer's answer. You just describe the set of pairs $\{x, 6-x\}$ (which is in fact a singleton if $x=3$, rather than a pair.)

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence class of $x$ is the two points  of distance $\mid x-3\mid$ from $3$ (except in the case of $x=3$, when there is just $\{3\}$).

The quotient will then be, for each $d\gt0$, the set of two points at distance $d$ from $3$, $\{3-d,3+d\}$, together with the singleton $\{3\}$.

Comment: Sorry, but how would you write that in mathematical terms?

Comment: $[x]=\{3-\mid x-3\mid,3+\mid x-3\mid\}\,,\forall x\in\mathbb R$.